# Remove Non English Characters PHP

Tags: php, character

how can i parse a string to remove all non english characters in php

right now I want to remove things like

სოფო ნი�

Thanks :)

Comment: I assume you mean non-Latin/Roman alphabetic characters.

Comment: yeah sorry that's what I meant

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^\00-\255]+/u', '', $str);
```

Comment: Octal 0 to 255, so decimal 0 to 173?

Comment: It's decimal 0 to 255. all the 256 ASCIIs.

Comment: Answer without any context. On top, this will not remove all non-English characters, just test it here https://regexr.com

Answer (score 11):

Your best option would be using `iconv`, which converts strings to requested character encoding.

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT',  $yourtext);
```

with `//translit` you get a meaningful conversion to ASCII (e.g. ß -> ss). Using //IGNORE will strip non-ascii characters altogether.

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE',  $yourtext);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer, yet, it will not remove things like `<!--` for example. And those aren't what the OP probably considers "valid EN characters". Upvoted for the creativity.

Answer (score 9):

By using [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/preg_replace)

```
$string = "some სოფო text"; 
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_ ]/i', '', $string); 

echo $string;
```

Granted, you will need to expand the [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) pattern, but that is one way to do it. There is probably a better way, I just do not know it.

Comment: This is the only correct answer, yet, it also still does not remove everything (empty spaces. But one could argue them to be valid EN Characters. If you want to remove empty characters too, you can wrap the entire pre_replace into a trim(). In any case, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score -3):

use this code:

```
$illegalChars = array("",); 
$string  = str_replace($illegalChars,"",$string );
echo $string;
```

Comment: you would need to compare against every non-english character

Comment: I would tend to use a "whitelist" approach rather than a "blacklist" approach. That is, I would have the routine identify the characters that should be kept, those characters that _ARE_ "english characters" and eliminating the rest, rather than trying to identify the characters that should be removed.