# Regular expression - preg_match Latin and Greek characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I am trying to create a regular expression for any given string.

**Goal**: remove ALL characters which are not "**latin**" or "**lowercase greek**" or "**numbers**" .

What I have done so far:  `[^a-z0-9]`
This works perfect for latin characters.

When I try this: `[^a-z0-9α-ω]` no luck. Works BUT leaves out any other symbol like !!#$%@%#$@,`

My knowledge is limited when it comes to regexp. Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Posted below is the function that matches characters specified and creates a slug out of it, with a dash as a separation character:

```
        $q_separator = preg_quote('-');
        $trans = array(
            '&.+?;'                 => '',
            '[^a-z0-9 -]'           => '',
            '\s+'                   => $separator,
            '('.$q_separator.')+'   => $separator
        );

        $str = strip_tags($str);

        foreach ($trans as $key => $val){
            $str = preg_replace("#".$key."#i", $val, $str);
        }

        if ($lowercase === TRUE){
            $str = strtolower($str);
        }

        return trim($str, '-');
```

So if the string is: **OnCE upon   a tIME !#% @$$ in MEXIco**
Using the function the output will be: **once-upon-a-time-in-mexico**

This works fine but I want the preg_match also to exclude **greek** characters.

Comment: Duplicate question with preg_match per OS ?

Comment: he has a good solution there ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, can this replace your function?

```
$subject = 'OnCEΨΩ é-+@àupon</span> aαθ tIME !#%@$ in MEXIco in the year 1874 <or 1875';

function format($str, $excludeRE = '/[^a-z0-9]+/u', $separator = '-') {
    $str = strip_tags($str);
    $str = strtolower($str);
    $str = preg_replace($excludeRE, $separator, $str);
    $str = trim($str, $separator);
    return $str;
}
echo format($subject);
```

Note that you will loose all characters after a `<` (cause of strip_tags) until you meet a `>`

---

// Old answer when I tought you wanted to preserve greek characters

It's possible to build a character range such as α-ω or any strange characters you want! The reason your pattern doesn't work is that you don't inform the regex engine you are dealing with a unicode string. To do that, you must add the `u` modifier at the end of the pattern. Like that:

```
/[^a-z0-9α-ω]+/u
```

You can use chars hexadecimal code too:

```
/[^a-z0-9\x{3B1}-\x{3C9}]+/u
```

Note that if you are sure not to have or want to preserve, uppercase Greek chars in your string, you can use the character class `\p{Greek}` like this :

```
/[^a-z0-9\p{Greek}]+/u
```

(It's a little longer but more explicit)

Comment: 1st solution works but symbols are still there
2nd solution error: Compilation failed: character value in \x{...} sequence is too large at offset 15
3rd solution works but also symbols are still there

Comment: Updated my question with some code

Comment: Ok, it's more clear now

Comment: Your function works with $excludeRE = '/[^a-z0-9α-ω]++/u'. I need to test if first for every case.

Answer (score 2):

There's already an answered question about this:

[Remove Non English Characters PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654879/remove-non-english-characters-php)

You can't specify a range such as α-ω but you need to use their code e.g. \00-\255

Comment: Where can I find those codes for greek characters. Or combine characters ranges or something similar