# is it possible to check whether a word in an array contains a non-english character

Tags: php

I am following this link [Remove Non English Characters PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654879/remove-non-english-characters-php)

But still i want to know is it possible to check whether a word in an **array** contains a non-english character.if yes.how?

thanks!

Comment: What don't you understand of the answer in the question you linked?

Comment: preg_match instead of preg_replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I [suggested in a comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658418/is-it-possible-to-check-whether-a-word-in-an-array-contains-a-non-english-charac/20659434#comment30928332_20658509), you can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) with a callback function to return the non-English words. Note that this uses the regular expression provided in [*h2ooooooo*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20658509/1438393):

```
$result = array_filter($array, function($word) { 
    return preg_match('/[^\00-\255]/', $word); 
});
```

Now, `$result` will be an array containing all the non-English words. If you're trying to check if your array contains **any** words that has non-English characters in it, then you could check the number of elements in the `$result` array using [`count()`](http://php.net/count):

```
if (count($result) > 0) {
    // at least a word containing non-English characters 
    // found in the array
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To almost completely copy paste the answer from the other thread, you can just use `preg_match`:

```
$foundNonEnglishCharacter = false;

foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (preg_match('/[^\00-\255]/', $word)) {
        $foundNonEnglishCharacter = true;
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($foundNonEnglishCharacter); //If true, there's a non-english character somewhere - if not, then there's no english characters.
```

Regex autopsy:

`[^\00-\255]` - Any character that *isn't* in the range of ASCII value 0 to 255 (hence, if anything matches, it **does** contain characters outside this scope)

You can find the regular 0-255 ascii values, and what they mean on [asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Good one 'Regex autopsy' :))

Comment: thanks for the answer .can i implement it to check for words in array?

Comment: @RishabhRaj: Use `array_filter`: `$new = array_filter($array, function($word) { return preg_match('/[^\00-\255]/', $word); });`

Comment: @AmalMurali post it as an answer and i will accept it :)

Comment: @RishabhRaj Check my edit - it simply replaces it with a loop instead.

Comment: @RishabhRaj: [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20659434/1438393).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible.

Using [Remove Non English Characters PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654879/remove-non-english-characters-php).

```
$strNew = preg_replace('/[^\00-\255]+/u', '', $str);
if($strNew == $str) {
    // all english
} else {
    // non-english character
}
```