# Full Text Search - Ignore polish letters in search phrase

Tags: php

Is it possible to ignore Polish characters in a search phrase using Full Text Search? For example, I have a movie in my database. This movie's title is: "Pięćdziesiąt twarzy Greya". If a visitor searches with the phrase: "piecdziesiat", my script should find a movie which contain phrase: "piecdziesiat" (and ignore any Polish letters).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strtr()` to convert a string with diacritics to a string without diacritics. For example, it can convert 'Pięćdziesiąt' to 'piecdziesiat'. There's a [comment on the PHP documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php#90925) with a useful function containing a good translation table.

For posterity's sake, that is:

```
function normalize ($string) {
    $table = array(
        'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Đ'=>'Dj', 'đ'=>'dj', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'Č'=>'C', 'č'=>'c', 'Ć'=>'C', 'ć'=>'c',
        'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
        'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O',
        'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss',
        'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e',
        'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o',
        'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b',
        'ÿ'=>'y', 'Ŕ'=>'R', 'ŕ'=>'r',
    );

    return strtr($string, $table);
}
```

So a user searches for "Pięćdziesiąt" and you turn that into "piecdziesiat" (you can run it through `strtolower()` as well). Then in your database you have a field for 'canonicalised version', which has stripped any diacritics. When you search in the database, you search on the canonical field instead of the title field.

Another option depends on which database you're using. PostgreSQL has an `unaccent` feature which lets you do this on the database side, without the need for a 'canonical' field. There's also the `UTF8-bin` mode in MySQL / MariaDB, and I'm pretty sure MongoDB has a similar function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using preg_replace? Found this topic for removing non-English chars

[Remove Non English Characters PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654879/remove-non-english-characters-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's own `iconv` function to tackle this problem.

```
$output = iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", $input);
```

A more detailed example can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#83238