# How to remove/filter non english value from a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, non-english

I have PHP indexed array. And it has some non-English elements like "სოფო ნი" or "で書く". I don't want to remove special characters and numbers. Now how can I remove the non-English elements from the array?

I want a direct filter for array, not just string.

Comment: Can you include a sample, expected output and what you have tried?

Comment: Why don't you work in reverse? Specify which characters you want to keep, it'll make life infinitely easier.

Comment: Take the solution from the duplicate and use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to apply it to each element of your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `$str = preg_replace('/[^\00-\255]+/u', '', $str);` to filter out those characters. Here's the function for it:

```
function filter($array){
 foreach ($array as $key => $value){
  $array[$key] = preg_replace('/[^\00-\255]+/u', '', $value); }
  return $array;
}
```

Already answered(for preg replace regex) here though: [Remove Non English Characters PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654879/remove-non-english-characters-php)

Comment: I want a direct filter for array, not just string.

Comment: Please don't copy answers, instead, flag this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Script47 Just used the regex, he needed a function. Though yes, I get your point.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired result by doing as follows:-

```
    $NonAsciiArray = [
    1  => "で書く",
    2  => "სოფონი",
    3  => "c",
    4  => "d",
   ];


$ArrayCleaned = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $NonAsciiArray );
var_dump($ArrayCleaned);
```

Tested. The `var_dump` of the array output shows that only c and d are printed. Other non-ASCII characters are ignored.

```
   array (size=4)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string '' (length=0)
  3 => string 'c' (length=1)
  4 => string 'd' (length=1)
```

If you want unset the array key which has no corresponding values.

```
foreach($ArrayCleaned as $key=>$value)
{   //Unset the  keys  with no values
    if(is_null($value) || $value == '')
        unset($ArrayCleaned[$key]);
}

foreach ($ArrayCleaned as $key => $value) {
    // print keny with thier values
    echo "{$key} => {$value} ";
}
```

Comment: I want to unset that non-english containing element from an array.How can I do that?

Comment: I have updated the answer. hope that helps you further

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution and pasted code below.

```
<?php
     $nonAsciiAray = [
        1  => "で書く",
        2  => "სოფო 1 ნი",
        3  => "Pavan",
        4  => "Vanam ი",
         ];

    foreach ($nonAsciiAray as $key => $value){
      $len1 = strlen($value);
      $value2 = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $value);
      $len2 = strlen($value2);
      if($len1 != $len2){
        unset($nonAsciiAray[$key]);
      }

    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($nonAsciiAray);
?>
```